# Calculate variable based on values of another variable

Tags: variables, types, spss, naming, data-entry

I'm learning SPSS for a research methods class but I'm a bit confused on how to enter and define values that represent a meaning after a certain point. For example, the problem I am working on states:

**Suppose the following indexed scores represent performance on a new survey meant to understand an individual’s level of depression. Suppose a score of above 20 represents a depressed individual based on the survey design.

Scores: 13.5, 15.7, 14.3, 16.7, 21.2, 20.7, 22.3, 17.4, 16.8, and 12.4

What is the relative frequency of those individuals that represent depressed individuals?**

How would one define or make the values over 20 marked as "depressed" to accurately calculate the relative frequency?

Please and thank you!

[Picture of the variables and question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb5j3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate a new variable based on the existing one which will have a value of 1 if the original variable is over the threshold, and 0 if not. There are a few ways to do that, this is the simplest one:

```
compute depressed=(score>-20).
```

You can now add labels and analyse:

```
value labels depressed 
    1  "depressed: score over 20"
    0  "score not over 20".
frequencies depressed.
```